# Remove preceding tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

If there is a tag as 
              `<p id="name" onclick="javascript:var ele=context(this);">sumtext here</p><br>`
              
`<p id="name" onclick="javascript:var ele=context(this);">newtext here</p><br>`

```
   <script>
    function context(obj)
     {
         var b = document.getelementbyID("area");
         b.removeChild(obj);
         //How to remove the preceding element i.e,<br>
     }
   </script>

    <textarea id='area' rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
```

`<p> and <br>` are not in a div and so if I remove `<p>` how to remove the preceding tag br from Javascript?

Comment: You shouldn't need `<br>` between `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `previousSibling()` to find the, er... previous sibling of an element:

```
b.removeChild(obj.previousSibling());
b.removeChild(obj);
```